# octave from ppa with packages not possible

Tags: 16.04, package-management, ppa, octave

I installed octave using ppa, but now all octave packages (e.g. optim) have broken dependencies.

I proceeded in the following way:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:octave/stable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install octave
```

If I now try to install any octave package I get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install octave-optim
[...]
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
octave-optim : Depends: liboctave3 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I can not solve this by installing liboctave3, since this package collides with octave from ppa:

```
$ sudo apt-get install liboctave3
[...]
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  octave
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  liboctave3
```

Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I use 16.04

Comment: Ok, I see. I have tried a few solutions but it seems the issue is persistent... Let me see what more I can cook up!

Answer (score 1):

The [PPA `ppa:octave/stable`](https://launchpad.net/~octave/+archive/ubuntu/stable?field.series_filter=xenial) do not contain packages named `liboctave3` and `octave-optim`. So the behavior is expected.

I see the following possible solutions:

- do not install `liboctave3` package, but use Octave from mentioned PPA and install `optim` package [from forge](https://octave.sourceforge.io/optim/index.html) with the following commands in terminal

  ```
  sudo apt-get install liboctave-dev
  ```

  and inside Octave shell

  ```
  pkg install -forge struct
  pkg install -forge io
  pkg install -forge statistics
  pkg install -forge optim
  ```
- purge the PPA and install Octave 4.0 from Ubuntu *universe* repositories and install needed packages:

  ```
  sudo ppa-purge ppa:octave/stable
  sudo add-apt-repository universe
  sudo apt-get install liboctave3 octave-optim
  ```